# Company is asking for my documents, salary slip etc but not told me status of my application yet

Tags: job-offer, new-job, hiring-process, india, documentation

I was interviewed by a company through 3rd party (Elitmus job portal) after 2 days I checked my status on Elitmus as "Not selected". Now after a week HR personally mailed me to fill a 4-page Employment application form and asking for my documents marksheet, ID proof, current company payslip etc but didn't tell me whether I'm selected on not.

**Should I ask about my application status before sharing the documents** and what is a suitable way to ask them?

Comment: Based on the info in the question, I've added the country tag, please revert if inappropriate.

Answer (score 4):

> *Should I ask about my application status before sharing the documents?*

#### Yes, obviously.

You need to ensure that you are in touch with the correct point of contact and not being scammed somehow. Do not share any personal information until you can confirm that it is about a legit job offer and not a scam.

> *what is a suitable way to ask them?*

Be direct and clear in the communication. Send an email asking for the clarity on the application / interview result status. Tell them the status you got to see / know is a negative one, and if actually that is a mistake / error, how you can be sure of the actual modified status.

They should be sending you a written communication mentioning the rectification in the status confirming your eligibility, and only then you should pursue further communication. Then again, the actual amount of information you want to share is withing your control - Documents with proof your identity, academic and previous work experience (if applicable) is commonplace to share, but the previous salary slip / payslip is NOT a must one. Use your best judgement.

Finally

> *...HR personally mailed me...*

I hope the communication is actually originated from a company email ID, not a personal (gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc.) or *professional-looking* one. If otherwise, it's a big red flag, stop communicating and run the other way, fast.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I used your advice and asked HR about my application status and didn't share my documents. But I haven't heard from her after that, it will be a week tomorrow. Should I send another mail to her or give her a call or should I just wait for a reply?